# Burn Ubuntu in USB for booting

Tags: usb, 18.04, burning, toshiba-satellite

What is the best software to burn Ubuntu in USB for booting without errors?

OS : Windows 10

USB : San disk 32 G.B

ISO File : Ubuntu 18.04 amd64

Laptop : Toshiba satellite c850

Comment: Seems like you did not read the instructions on the download page. Here they are again: https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Im Using Rufus, the best tool for windows

https://rufus.akeo.ie/

You have another tools like

https://unetbootin.github.io/

Answer (score 2):

You need to define what you call best.

I would suggest Etcher, https://etcher.io/; it's designed to avoid mistake of newbie flashing the wrong drive.

<strike>As a side note, what a waste to use a 32GB drive just to flash a 1.9GB iso.</strike>

Comment: But USB  drives are temporary devices, and I guess the Sandisk is a fast USB 3 pendrive, which makes things fast and convenient. After installing, the OP can re-use the pendrive for other purposes ;-) The following link may add some useful details [Installation/FromUSBStick](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick)